# Fastest way to test for day of year

Tags: postgresql

I would like to check whether the values in a `DATE` column fall on 29 Feb independent of year? What is the fastest way to perform this check in Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

Either extract day and month as numbers:

```
where extract(month from the_column) = 2
  and extract(day from the_column) = 29
```

or use `to_char()`

```
where to_char(the_column, 'ddmm') = '2902'
```

Both expressions will probably have the same performance, but neither of them is able to use an index on `the_column`